# AMcharts data population from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, amcharts

Hi I have a chart which is rendering and the key is displaying as well as the column titles.

My issue is I cant get the actual bar to generate from the values I am passing.

My php code is fine and I am using the function json_encode when returning the data. Here is the returned Data being passed to the chart code :

```
[{"gid":"NickShare","Users":1},
{"gid":"admin","Users":2},
{"gid":"sharedTest","Users":2}]
```

Here is my JQuery Code for the chart :

```
  function supportsSVG() {
        return !!document.createElementNS && !!document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "svg").createSVGRect;
    }
var token = $('#_token').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'getShares',
    type: 'post',
    //  dataType:'json',
    data: {
        _token: token,

    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {

        var DBData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        UserGroupsBar = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
       // var Data = [{}];

        UserGroupsBar.dataProvider = DBData;
        UserGroupsBar.startDuration = 1;
        UserGroupsBar.categoryField = "gid";

        $.each(DBData, function (i, item) {
          //  alert(item['Users']);
            if (item['Users'] > 0) {

               // Data[0][item['gid'] = item['Users']];
                var UserGroupGraph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                UserGroupGraph.id = item['gid'];
                UserGroupGraph.valueField = item['Users'];
                UserGroupGraph.title = item['gid'];
                UserGroupGraph.type = "column";
                UserGroupGraph.lineAlpha = 0;
                UserGroupGraph.fillAlphas = 1;
                UserGroupGraph.balloonText = "[[title]]: [[value]]";
                UserGroupsBar.addGraph(UserGroupGraph);
            }
        });

        UserGroupsBar.write("BarChart");

        var GroupValueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        GroupValueAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
        GroupValueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
        GroupValueAxis.integersOnly = true;
        UserGroupsBar.addValueAxis(GroupValueAxis);
        UserGroupsBar.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
        UserGroupsBar.outlineAlpha = 0.2;
        UserGroupsBar.outlineThickness = 2;
        UserGroupsBar.startDuration = supportsSVG() ? 1 : 0;
        UserGroupsBar.depth3D = supportsSVG() ? 20 : 0;
        UserGroupsBar.angle = supportsSVG() ? 30 : 0;
        //Root Causes Legend
        GroupLegend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
        UserGroupsBar.addLegend(GroupLegend, "Legend");
        GroupLegend.valueText = "";
        GroupLegend.align = "center";
        GroupLegend.position = "absolute";
        GroupLegend.marginTop = 30;
        GroupLegend.markerType = "circle";
        GroupLegend.labelWidth = 180;
        GroupLegend.fontSize = 10;
        GroupLegend.verticalGap = 20;
        // WRITE
        UserGroupsBar.write("BarChart");
    }


});
```

It seems really close to working now I know I must just be missing something silly but I have been staring at it to long. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Cheers;
NE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueField` should point to an actual field in data by it's name, while you seem to be assigning its value. To fix replace this line:

```
UserGroupGraph.valueField = item['Users'];
```

Into this:

```
UserGroupGraph.valueField = 'Users';
```